# Python find min & max of two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists such as:

```
l_one = [2,5,7,9,3]
l_two = [4,6,9,11,4]
```

...and I need to find the min and max value from both lists combined. That is, I want to generate a single min and a single max value.

My question is - what is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Should this be tagged homework?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Arguably the most readable way is

```
max(l_one + l_two)
```

or

```
min(l_one + l_two)
```

It will copy the lists, though, since `l_one + l_two` creates a new list.  To avoid copying, you could do

```
max(max(l_one), max(l_two))
min(min(l_one), min(l_two))
```

Comment: So the first one will copy the list and find out the maxim (more expensive on memory). But what about the second method, does it take longer speed wise?

Comment: @George: No, it's also faster.  The only disadvantage is that it does not read just as nice as the first one.

Comment: Can you please explain or provide me with resources so I can learn the reasoning behind it? Should I ask this as an new question? Or it is very trivial / depend on the implementation.

Comment: @George: The reasoning behind what?

Comment: Why `max(l_one + l_two)` is also faster than `max(max(l_one), max(l_two))`. Thank you Sven.

Comment: @George: The first form creates a new list, which will contain copies of all the references in `l_one` and `l_two`.  This step takes some time proportional to the length of the lists.  The second form doesn't need the copying, so its faster.  (It has to call `max()` three times, though, so for very short lists it might even be a tad slower, but for very short lists, speed doesn't matter anyway.)

Comment: @George, often one method is faster with small lists while the other is faster with longer lists. In this example I see that when the lists are 1000 items the second way is faster.

Answer (score 17):

Another way that avoids copying the lists

```
>>> l_one = [2,5,7,9,3]
>>> l_two = [4,6,9,11,4]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> max(chain(l_one, l_two))
11
>>> min(chain(l_one, l_two))
2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine them and then call min or max:

```
>>> l_one = [2,5,7,9,3]
>>> l_two = [4,6,9,11,4]
>>> min(l_one + l_two)
2
>>> max(l_one + l_two)
11
```

Answer (score 3):

(Modified thanks do AndreasT comment. Removed the "min(min())" solution )

You may even have a smarter solution which works with different numpy array :

```
import numpy as np
i1=np.array(range(5))
i2=np.array(range(4))
i3=np.array(range(-5,5))
np.min(np.concatenate([i1,i2,i3]))
```

Comment: `min(min([i1,i2,i3]))` does not produce the wanted result.
`min(min([10,2,3], [4,5], [10]))` gives `4` as output, whereas the sought minimum is `2`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the maximum or minimum values from the two lists.I think the following will work:

```
from numpy import maximum
result = maximum(l_one,l_two)
```

It will return a maximum value after comparing each element in this two lists.